# converting html form to use django form library

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django and I didnt know that it included a forms library. I have written a dynamic form in html and javascript that shows checkboxes and if clicked, they display more input fields.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to adapt the code that I have already written to use django's forms library since it is so much easier and cleaner to access the form's data with djangos built-in methods.

Also, if i want the form to be dynamic do I need to use formset or does the form library have those capabilities?

Here is the code I would like to convert to use the Forms library:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
        function ifChecked(id, id2){
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        var ele2 = document.getElementById(id2);

        if(ele.checked){
            ele2.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            ele2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function ifCheckedLine(id, id2){
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        var ele2 = document.getElementById(id2);

        if(ele.checked){
            ele2.style.display = "inline";
        }
        else{
            ele2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
<form name="myform" action="resultsget" method = "get" >            
        <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" value="total_money" id = "money_check" name="check" onchange="javascript:ifChecked('money_check','money');" /> Filter by Total Money</br>

                <div id="money" style="display:none" name="option">  

                    <input type="checkbox" value="more" id="money_condition" onchange="javascript:ifCheckedLine('money_condition', 'money_text');"  name="condition"/> <label for="condition" > > </label>

                        <div id = "money_text" style="display:none"  >
                            <input type="text" id="money_box" name="money_name" value="lower limit" />
                        </div></br>

                    <input type="checkbox" value="less" id="money_condition1" onchange="javascript:ifCheckedLine('money_condition1', 'money_text1');" name="condition"/> <label for="condition1"> < </label>

                        <div id = "money_text1" style="display:none;"  >
                            <input type="text" id="money_box1" name="money_name1" value="upper limit" />
                        </div>

                </div> 
</fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>​
```

I would also like to know what I have to put in my views.py file to read the form information

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With django forms you can build a form with fields that you want and using template render it.
Processing of a form will become easy when you build a django form. Refer [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

For dynamic enabling/disabling fields, the code you have written can be used with a change that use 'id' that django puts in for form field. I will suggest to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to set event handlers for the elements.

Comment: Oh I didnt know my javascript could work with the django forms! How would I reference the separate checkboxes and values of the django forms in the javascript?
@Rohan

Comment: Oh I didnt know my javascript could work with the django forms! How would I reference the separate checkboxes and values of the django forms in the javascript?
@Rohan

Comment: @Santiago You can start by looking at the source of page (or chrome developer tools) and identify ids or names of fields that you want to manipulate.

Comment: This is great. Last question, how can add event attributes (onchange)to the django forms? @Rohan

Comment: @Santiago, I would suggest you do that using javascript (better jQuery).

Comment: any suggestions on how I can do that? Ive never used JQuery @Rohan